# How to get Active div id in the contentEditable div using Jquery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get the active div id in the contntEditable div when typing the text.Kindly provide the solution.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: bind key events and use `this` to get the id of it.

Comment: If i have 10 divs in  contntEditable div.If I am typing the text in the 3rd div means, i need to get the 3rd div id.From that i need to apply the css styles

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `id` of target element using `JQuery` by:

```
$('div').on('click', function(e){
    alert(e.target.id);    
});
```

However you are more interested in changing the `CSS` of the target then there is no need to get the `id`.You can just do:

```
$('div').on('click', function(){
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow"); 
});
```

EDIT:

Yes you can using `mouseover` event also

```
$('div').mouseover(function(e){
    alert(e.target.id);    
});
```

Comment: I need without click events,there is a chance of mouse move up or mouse move down in the contentEditable Div.

Comment: Arrow Up and down Down keys we have any events?

Comment: Yes there are events for those also.List of events https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_events.asp  If this is what you are looking for then please accept the answer